# https://localhost:631 insists on login even with lpadmin

Tags: login, cups

is anybody else having trouble with cups wanting my root password whenever I need to fix the printer? I am lpadmin group.  This is certainly a bit of a security issue IMHO.

Comment: raspberry Pi OS doesn't set a root password - I take it you've added one, or is it asking for your user password in order to run something "sudo" - and why would asking for a password be a security issue?